# Eclipse ADT Bundle: fatal error, not able to start

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, java

I have downloaded the ADT Bundle for Linux (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) that includes android sdk + eclipse with ADT plugin.

After extracting the .ZIP file, double click on eclipse... I choose the default workspace and the application crashes... one log gets created. Here is its content:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9c7a8b52c0, pid=11965, tid=140310293825280
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.2-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x192c0]  g_object_get_qdata+0x20
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f9c80009800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=11966, stack(0x00007f9c8928c000,0x00007f9c8938d000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000000000000c8

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000000000c8, RBX=0x00007f9c807ceae0, RCX=0x0000000000000358, RDX=0x00007f9c807ceae0
RSP=0x00007f9c89389af0, RBP=0x0000000000000358, RSI=0x0000000000000358, RDI=0x00007f9c807ceae0
R8 =0x00007f9c7d005400, R9 =0x00000000c0e8a400, R10=0x00007f9c7d011f64, R11=0x00007f9c880110b0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000c0ef1120, R14=0x00007f9c89389ba8, R15=0x00007f9c80009800
RIP=0x00007f9c7a8b52c0, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f9c89389af0)
0x00007f9c89389af0:   00007f9c89389b40 00000000c0ef1120
0x00007f9c89389b00:   00007f9c89389b78 00007f9c4aec1ef6
0x00007f9c89389b10:   00000000d004cec0 00007f9c7d011f90
0x00007f9c89389b20:   0000000000000001 00000000f08ecaa8
0x00007f9c89389b30:   0000000000000001 00007f9c89389b38
0x00007f9c89389b40:   0000000000000000 00007f9c89389ba8
0x00007f9c89389b50:   00000000c0f82828 0000000000000000
0x00007f9c89389b60:   00000000c0ef1120 0000000000000000
0x00007f9c89389b70:   00007f9c89389b98 00007f9c89389bf0
0x00007f9c89389b80:   00007f9c7d006275 00000000f08eaa08
0x00007f9c89389b90:   00007f9c7d00edd7 0000000000000358
0x00007f9c89389ba0:   00007f9c807ceae0 0000000000000001
0x00007f9c89389bb0:   00007f9c89389bb0 00000000c0ef1229
0x00007f9c89389bc0:   00007f9c89389c28 00000000c0f82828
0x00007f9c89389bd0:   0000000000000000 00000000c0ef1268
0x00007f9c89389be0:   00007f9c89389b98 00007f9c89389c18
0x00007f9c89389bf0:   00007f9c89389c70 00007f9c7d006275
0x00007f9c89389c00:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f9c89389c10:   0000000000000000 0000000000000358
0x00007f9c89389c20:   00007f9c807ceae0 0000000000000000
0x00007f9c89389c30:   00007f9c89389c30 00000000c0e8a37b
0x00007f9c89389c40:   00007f9c89389ca0 00000000c0eb8d00
0x00007f9c89389c50:   0000000000000000 00000000c0e8a400
0x00007f9c89389c60:   00007f9c89389c18 00007f9c89389c90
0x00007f9c89389c70:   00007f9c89389ce8 00007f9c7d006333
0x00007f9c89389c80:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f9c89389c90:   00007f9c807ceae0 00000000f0cd2f58
0x00007f9c89389ca0:   00000000f0903fa8 00007f9c89389ca8
0x00007f9c89389cb0:   00000000c113bed5 00007f9c89389d08
0x00007f9c89389cc0:   00000000c11439c0 0000000000000000
0x00007f9c89389cd0:   00000000c113bf58 00007f9c89389c90
0x00007f9c89389ce0:   00007f9c89389d08 00007f9c89389d50 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f9c7a8b52c0)
0x00007f9c7a8b52a0:   48 89 5c 24 f0 48 89 6c 24 f8 48 83 ec 18 48 85
0x00007f9c7a8b52b0:   ff 48 89 fb 74 21 48 8b 07 89 f5 48 85 c0 74 06
0x00007f9c7a8b52c0:   48 83 38 50 74 42 be 50 00 00 00 48 89 df e8 8d
0x00007f9c7a8b52d0:   83 01 00 85 c0 75 31 48 8d 15 92 1c 02 00 48 8d 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000000000c8 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007f9c807ceae0 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000358 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f9c807ceae0 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f9c89389af0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9c80009800
RBP=0x0000000000000358 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000358 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00007f9c807ceae0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f9c7d005400 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000000c0e8a400 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R10=0x00007f9c7d011f64 is an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x00007f9c7d011d00, 0x00007f9c7d012540]  2112 bytes
R11=0x00007f9c880110b0: <offset 0x7810b0> in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f9c87890000
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000c0ef1120 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x00007f9c89389ba8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9c80009800
R15=0x00007f9c80009800 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007f9c8928c000,0x00007f9c8938d000],  sp=0x00007f9c89389af0,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x192c0]  g_object_get_qdata+0x20

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xb]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_object_get_qdata(JI)J+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_object_get_qdata(JI)J+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.removeWidget(J)Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget;+19
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.deregister()V+21
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.releaseWidget()V+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.releaseWidget()V+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseWidget()V+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.releaseWidget()V+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Z)V+82
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Z)V+94
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Z)V+31
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Z)V+38
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Z)V+94
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Z)V+31
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Z)V+38
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Z)V+94
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Z)V+31
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Z)V+38
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Z)V+94
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Z)V+31
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Z)V+38
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Z)V+94
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Z)V+31
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Z)V+42
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Z)V+22
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Z)V+100
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Z)V+38
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Z)V+94
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose()V+23
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose()V+20
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.close()Z+65
j  org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.close()Z+26
j  org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.okPressed()V+6
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.okPressed()V+15
j  org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(I)V+5
j  org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionEvent;)V+17
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+1133
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+214
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+25
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents()Z+92
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+46
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)V+23
j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open()I+49
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(Z)V+15
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/ide/ChooseWorkspaceData;Z)Ljava/net/URL;+15
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+50
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000001206000 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=11995, stack(0x00007f9c4b490000,0x00007f9c4b591000)]
  0x0000000001098000 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11992, stack(0x00007f9c4b5d1000,0x00007f9c4b6d2000)]
  0x0000000001135800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11988, stack(0x00007f9c4b7d3000,0x00007f9c4b8d4000)]
  0x00007f9c80540000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11987, stack(0x00007f9c4b6d2000,0x00007f9c4b7d3000)]
  0x00007f9c80523000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11985, stack(0x00007f9c4b8d4000,0x00007f9c4b9d5000)]
  0x00007f9c80522000 JavaThread "State Saver" [_thread_blocked, id=11984, stack(0x00007f9c4b9d5000,0x00007f9c4bad6000)]
  0x00007f9c804ee800 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=11983, stack(0x00007f9c4bad6000,0x00007f9c4bbd7000)]
  0x00007f9c80192000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11976, stack(0x00007f9c7acfd000,0x00007f9c7adfe000)]
  0x00007f9c80190000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11975, stack(0x00007f9c7adfe000,0x00007f9c7aeff000)]
  0x00007f9c8018d000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11974, stack(0x00007f9c7aeff000,0x00007f9c7b000000)]
  0x00007f9c8018b000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11973, stack(0x00007f9c8407e000,0x00007f9c8417f000)]
  0x00007f9c80135000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11971, stack(0x00007f9c8444a000,0x00007f9c8454b000)]
  0x00007f9c80132800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11970, stack(0x00007f9c8454b000,0x00007f9c8464c000)]
=>0x00007f9c80009800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=11966, stack(0x00007f9c8928c000,0x00007f9c8938d000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007f9c8012a000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f9c8464c000,0x00007f9c8474d000] [id=11969]
  0x00007f9c8019d000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f9c7abfc000,0x00007f9c7acfd000] [id=11977]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 88960K, used 13784K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f99a0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 78784K, 17% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0d763c0,0x00000000f4cf0000)
  from space 10176K, 0% used [0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f56e0000)
  to   space 15616K, 0% used [0x00000000f8a60000,0x00000000f8a60000,0x00000000f99a0000)
 ParOldGen       total 43072K, used 22279K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d2a10000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 43072K, 51% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d15c1c68,0x00000000d2a10000)
 PSPermGen       total 23936K, used 17774K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c1760000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 23936K, 74% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c115b818,0x00000000c1760000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00007f9c85def000,0x00007f9c85ff0000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f9c857ef000

Polling page: 0x00007f9c8928b000

Code Cache  [0x00007f9c7d000000, 0x00007f9c7d270000, 0x00007f9c80000000)
 total_blobs=856 nmethods=421 adapters=387 free_code_cache=47393Kb largest_free_block=48499776

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 11,144 Thread 0x00007f9c80190000  418             java.io.FilterInputStream::read (8 bytes)
Event: 11,147 Thread 0x00007f9c80190000 nmethod 418 0x00007f9c7d1a5610 code [0x00007f9c7d1a5780, 0x00007f9c7d1a5a68]
Event: 11,510 Thread 0x00007f9c80190000  419             java.util.HashMap::put (124 bytes)
Event: 11,546 Thread 0x00007f9c8018d000  420             org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.KeyedHashSet::add (194 bytes)
Event: 11,561 Thread 0x00007f9c80190000 nmethod 419 0x00007f9c7d1b8950 code [0x00007f9c7d1b8b80, 0x00007f9c7d1b95a0]
Event: 11,570 Thread 0x00007f9c8018d000 nmethod 420 0x00007f9c7d1b9e90 code [0x00007f9c7d1ba0c0, 0x00007f9c7d1ba810]
Event: 11,637 Thread 0x00007f9c80190000  421             java.lang.reflect.Field::getModifiers (5 bytes)
Event: 11,637 Thread 0x00007f9c80190000 nmethod 421 0x00007f9c7d1bc590 code [0x00007f9c7d1bc6c0, 0x00007f9c7d1bc718]
Event: 11,955 Thread 0x00007f9c80190000  422             java.util.zip.ZipFile::access$400 (5 bytes)
Event: 11,956 Thread 0x00007f9c80190000 nmethod 422 0x00007f9c7d1bbf90 code [0x00007f9c7d1bc0c0, 0x00007f9c7d1bc118]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 4,106 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=6 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 22272K, used 22272K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f3220000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 20608K, 100% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f1420000,0x00000000f1420000)
  from space 1664K, 100% used [0x00000000f1420000,0x00000000f15c0000,0x00000000f15c0000)
  to   space 5056K, 0% used [0x00000000f2d30000,0x00000000f2d30000,0x00000000f3220000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 9351K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 34% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d0921eb0,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 8767K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 41% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c088fcc0,0x00000000c14c0000)
Event: 4,120 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=6 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 45440K, used 5050K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f33c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 40384K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f2770000)
  from space 5056K, 99% used [0x00000000f2d30000,0x00000000f321e978,0x00000000f3220000)
  to   space 5888K, 0% used [0x00000000f2770000,0x00000000f2770000,0x00000000f2d30000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 9726K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 35% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d097fbc8,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 8767K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 41% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c088fcc0,0x00000000c14c0000)
}
Event: 4,809 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 45440K, used 45434K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f33c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 40384K, 100% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f2770000,0x00000000f2770000)
  from space 5056K, 99% used [0x00000000f2d30000,0x00000000f321e978,0x00000000f3220000)
  to   space 5888K, 0% used [0x00000000f2770000,0x00000000f2770000,0x00000000f2d30000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 9726K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 35% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d097fbc8,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 8794K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 41% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c0896908,0x00000000c14c0000)
Event: 4,847 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 46272K, used 5856K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f5ee0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 40384K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f2770000)
  from space 5888K, 99% used [0x00000000f2770000,0x00000000f2d283a0,0x00000000f2d30000)
  to   space 8192K, 0% used [0x00000000f56e0000,0x00000000f56e0000,0x00000000f5ee0000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 12830K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 46% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d0c87860,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 8794K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 41% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c0896908,0x00000000c14c0000)
}
Event: 5,333 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=8 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 46272K, used 46240K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f5ee0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 40384K, 100% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f2770000,0x00000000f2770000)
  from space 5888K, 99% used [0x00000000f2770000,0x00000000f2d283a0,0x00000000f2d30000)
  to   space 8192K, 0% used [0x00000000f56e0000,0x00000000f56e0000,0x00000000f5ee0000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 12830K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 46% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d0c87860,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 8812K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 41% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c089b148,0x00000000c14c0000)
Event: 5,369 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 86976K, used 8186K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f62c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 78784K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f4cf0000)
  from space 8192K, 99% used [0x00000000f56e0000,0x00000000f5ede838,0x00000000f5ee0000)
  to   space 10176K, 0% used [0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f56e0000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 14754K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 53% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d0e688e8,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 8812K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 41% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c089b148,0x00000000c14c0000)
}
Event: 10,168 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=9 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 86976K, used 86970K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f62c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 78784K, 100% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f4cf0000)
  from space 8192K, 99% used [0x00000000f56e0000,0x00000000f5ede838,0x00000000f5ee0000)
  to   space 10176K, 0% used [0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f56e0000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 14754K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 53% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d0e688e8,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 11684K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 54% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c0b69368,0x00000000c14c0000)
Event: 10,237 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=9 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 88960K, used 10162K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f99a0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 78784K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f4cf0000)
  from space 10176K, 99% used [0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f56dcb78,0x00000000f56e0000)
  to   space 15616K, 0% used [0x00000000f8a60000,0x00000000f8a60000,0x00000000f99a0000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 24666K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 90% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d1816b28,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 11684K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 54% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c0b69368,0x00000000c14c0000)
}
Event: 10,237 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=10 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 88960K, used 10162K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f99a0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 78784K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f4cf0000)
  from space 10176K, 99% used [0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f56dcb78,0x00000000f56e0000)
  to   space 15616K, 0% used [0x00000000f8a60000,0x00000000f8a60000,0x00000000f99a0000)
 ParOldGen       total 27328K, used 24666K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d1ab0000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 27328K, 90% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d1816b28,0x00000000d1ab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 11684K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c14c0000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 21248K, 54% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c0b69368,0x00000000c14c0000)
Event: 10,447 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=10 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 88960K, used 0K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f99a0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 78784K, 0% used [0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f0000000,0x00000000f4cf0000)
  from space 10176K, 0% used [0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f4cf0000,0x00000000f56e0000)
  to   space 15616K, 0% used [0x00000000f8a60000,0x00000000f8a60000,0x00000000f99a0000)
 ParOldGen       total 43072K, used 22279K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d2a10000, 0x00000000f0000000)
  object space 43072K, 51% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d15c1c68,0x00000000d2a10000)
 PSPermGen       total 23936K, used 11680K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c1760000, 0x00000000d0000000)
  object space 23936K, 48% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c0b681f8,0x00000000c1760000)
}
```

--
EDIT:

Well, I solved! I was trying to open an existing eclipse-workspace directory, with some old projects in it (created with an old version of Eclipse). If I select a new workspace directory... the program starts fine!

Comment: It look the same issue here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314312/java-application-crash

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem... The error remains, even with JDK6

Comment: This happens with CDT as well. Probably any kind of Eclipse variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved! I was trying to open an existing eclipse-workspace directory, with some old projects in it (created with an old version of Eclipse). If I select a new workspace directory... the program starts fine!

Answer (score 1):

I got to this page while searching for "Java crash in libglib-2.0 after Ubuntu/Linux Mint upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10".

So in case you're using Ubuntu 13.10 / Linux Mint 16 and having the exact same problem as me:

Solution is: (in KDE)

System Settings > Application Appearance > GTK

Set GTK2 Theme: Raleigh works excellent as workaround.

(for Unity or other desktop, you need to find how to change the GTK(2) theme)

References:

1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1241101
2. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=324438

Answer (score 1):

add below line to the end of your eclipse.ini

```
Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

(this help me in **linux mint 17 mate**)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try a different version of eclipse or of the java jdk. This issue is not related to android or adt but to eclipse only as the stack trace indicates.

Comment: Yep, I'll try a different jdk build

Answer (score 0):

Try to install JDK 1.6. ADT download page lists JDK 6 as system requirement.

Comment: I'll try a different version of jdk.

Comment: Did you try OpenJDK? What if you try Oracle JDK?

Comment: Ok, one more try: try to install SWT package which your Linux distribution can provide.

Comment: I've downloaded SWT x86_64bit from this page: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/ But I don't know how to install it... when I run "java -jar filename..." it tells me "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute"

Comment: What is Lunux distributive?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries

Comment: I don't even have this path ~/.swt/

Comment: You can try re-install `libgobject`, run `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`

Comment: Should I restart the system after that? Still nothing... the error is the same (at the top of log file): # Problematic frame:
# C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x192c0]  __float128+0x20

Comment: This problem is frustrating to me! I cannot finally program Android, till I'll be able to solve this issue. Thanks for your patience, I'll let you know if I find a solution

Comment: Well, I solved! I was trying to open an existing eclipse-workspace directory, with some old projects in it (created with an old version of Eclipse). If I select a new workspace directory... the program starts fine!